# How can I add multiple offset edges between two nodes in Cytoscape JS?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, cytoscape.js

I'd like to build parallel offset edges between two nodes in cytoscape. Is this possible? I was looking up solutions and the closest thing i found was http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/c408363501ccc4410dbd. Although this is a D3 solution.

Answer (score 2):

Bundled [bezier edges](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/bezier-edges) are the general solution for that problem.  You can tighten up beziers with `control-point-step-size`, making them straighter with smaller values.

A series of straight, parallel edges is not a general solution:  You run out of room too quickly, especially if there are one or more small nodes.  The general solution for several straight edges is [haystack edges](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/haystack-edges), which may overlap.

Unless you hand-craft all of your graphs or your graphs have guaranteed restrictions on parallel edges, a general solution is needed.  Otherwise, your graphs will be malformed -- and look broken to your users.

If bundled beziers or haystacks don't meet your requirements, then please [make a new feature request](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new).